# Rewrite post type into a page with year filter

Tags: rewrite-rules

I managed to put the posts of a post type 'whatsnew-list' into a page template. However, if I put the year and the end of the url it shows 404.(www.example.com/mypage/2018). How can I filter posts by year from a page template?

This is the rewrite rule I made, but it is not working

```
add_action('init', 'post_type_year_filter');
function post_type_year_filter(){
   add_rewrite_rule('^mypage/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?','index.php?post_type=whatsnew-list&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]','top');
   add_rewrite_rule('^mypage/([0-9]{4})/?','index.php?post_type=whatsnew-list&year=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Comment: Please make sure you flush your permastucture everytime you edit it. You can do so bij going to pemalinks settings form and saving it.

Comment: @Fleuv, I always save permalink every time I save my code